# Wacky IK arm Movement

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

I have an arm rig shown below.  C stands for control, and D stands for deform.

[image: rig]

I'm having a problem where when I try to move C_Hand in order to move the forearm, it does move, but it spins around wildly.  Impossible to animate!

Here's a picture of the C_D_forearm's IK constraint:

[image: IK_Constraint]

Does anybody know the solution?  If I haven't given enough information, please let me know.  If this is a duplicate, I apologize.

**Edit:**

I figured out that by unparenting C_Hand from C_D_forearm, the problem would be solved.  However, I'm almost positive that it should still be parented to C_D_forearm.  Can anybody clue me in?

Comment: I noticed the problem is fixed when I unparent C_hand from C_D_forearm.  But it seems like it should be parented to it.  ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes you need to unparent the IK controller, otherwise it creates a bug because the bone that is controlled is not supposed to control its master.

Also:

- I would put the controller vertically so that you don't confuse it with the hand.
- Parent the hand to the controller if it's not already.
- If you want the hand to stick to the forearm, give it a *Copy Location* constraint with the forearm as *Target* with a *Head/Tail* value of 1 so that it sticks to the tail and *Space* > *Pose Space* <-> *Pose Space*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for letting me know it did not have to be parented that way!  The only reason I cant move the hand controller vertically is because it also controls the rotation of the hand bone.

Comment: well, it won't change anything if you put a vertical controller, on the contrary, it will make the control easier because the controller won't be hidden

Comment: yeah, but I'm using a rotation constraint, so if I put it vertical, the hand bone will go vertical.

Comment: ok, but why are you using a rotation constraint? to control the hand? if you parent the hand to the controller, it won't need any rotation constraint...

Comment: I tried parenting the hand bone to the controller in edit mode, but it didn't follow the controller's rotation in pose mode.

Comment: I don't understand how that's possible...

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: of course: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6422" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6422/)

Comment: Ah!  Got it!  I had turned of Inherit Rotation.  I was following a book, which told me to do that, and it also said to instead use copy rotation constraint.

Comment: so when you were talking about making the hand stick to the forearm, u said add a copy location constraint..... to which bone?

Comment: add a copy location constraint to the hand if you want it to stick to the forearm when you move the controller

Comment: what do you mean if I don't want it to stick to the FOREARM when I move the controller.  Isn't the whole purpose to keep it stuck to the forearm at all times?

Comment: yes sorry I meant if you want it to stick to the forearm of course  ;)

Comment: OK, thanks a lot!  That was everything I needed!  Thanks for being so helpful!

Comment: (it's stupid that I get 2 points for accepting an answer to my own question.)